# How can I get VB.NET to output an XML file from pre-made XML code?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm working on a program right now that handles fixing computer settings that my department commonly fixes on the regular. One such setting is an 802.1x profile configuration for 2 different network adapters. The program needs to change the authentication to "User Authentication" in Local Area Network and Ethernet Adapter settings.

To deal with this currently, we have a program called BigFix that allows us to make packages and have them deployed over the network to make such changes. Our current fix is telling BigFix using BigFix action script to create an XML file in a directory, and then execute it with netsh commands, importing the settings.

My problem is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to take the pre-made XML script and get VB.NET to output it to an .xml file. An even bigger problem here is tat I know VB.NET has tools to do this, but I do not know how to script in XML AT ALL.

Could someone potentially point me to a solution / show me how to do what I'm looking to do? Here is the XML document below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/LAN/profile/v1">
  <MSM>
    <security>
      <OneXEnforced>false</OneXEnforced>
      <OneXEnabled>true</OneXEnabled>
      <OneX xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/OneX/v1">
        <cacheUserData>true</cacheUserData>
        <authMode>user</authMode>
        <EAPConfig>
          <EapHostConfig xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapHostConfig">
            <EapMethod>
              <Type xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">25</Type>
              <VendorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorId>
              <VendorType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</VendorType>
              <AuthorId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/EapCommon">0</AuthorId>
            </EapMethod>
            <Config>
              <Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                <Type>25</Type>
                <EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                  <ServerValidation>
                    <DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>false</DisableUserPromptForServerValidation>
                    <ServerNames />
                  </ServerValidation>
                  <FastReconnect>true</FastReconnect>
                  <InnerEapOptional>false</InnerEapOptional>
                  <Eap xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/BaseEapConnectionPropertiesV1">
                    <Type>26</Type>
                    <EapType xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsChapV2ConnectionPropertiesV1">
                      <UseWinLogonCredentials>true</UseWinLogonCredentials>
                    </EapType>
                  </Eap>
                  <EnableQuarantineChecks>false</EnableQuarantineChecks>
                  <RequireCryptoBinding>false</RequireCryptoBinding>
                  <PeapExtensions>
                    <PerformServerValidation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2">true</PerformServerValidation>
                    <AcceptServerName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/provisioning/MsPeapConnectionPropertiesV2">false</AcceptServerName>
                  </PeapExtensions>
                </EapType>
              </Eap>
            </Config>
          </EapHostConfig>
        </EAPConfig>
      </OneX>
    </security>
  </MSM>
</LANProfile>
```

Comment: What is this "pre-made XML script " ?

Answer (score 0):

Does following code help?

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.IO

Module Module1
    Const INPUT_FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.txt"
    Const OUTPUT_FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = File.ReadAllText(INPUT_FILENAME)

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)

        doc.Save(OUTPUT_FILENAME)

    End Sub

End Module
```